# Spivak chapet 7 problem 3. 4th edition, can someone help?

Tags: foundations

Prove that there is some number $x$ such that

(i) $\displaystyle{x^{179} + \frac{163}{1 + x^2 + \sin^2 x} = 119}$

(ii) $\sin x = x - 1$

I am not sure what to do, can someone show me what to do?

Comment: Hint:  look at what happens as $x\rightarrow ±\infty$

Comment: Further to lulu's hint and Mario G's answer, some things to think about are the continuity of the functions over their domains of definition (here all of the Reals). What are the ranges of $x^{179}$, of $1+x^2+sin^2x$, and so does the denominator go to zero, etc...

Comment: i think we get three Solutions for (iii)

Answer (score 1):

For (ii) let $f:[0,3]\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(t)=t-\sin t-1$, this is a continuous function, since $f(0)=-1$ and $f(3)=2-\sin 3>0$ it follows, from the Intermediate Value Theorem, that there is $x\in[0,3]$ such that $f(x)=0$.